# Linear Algebra (Ax=B)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am having some difficulty thinking about a certain concept in my linear notes.

I will post below the theorem that is involved,

Theorem: Let X$_0$ be a particular solution of the system AX = B (that is, assume AX$_0$= B).

(1) If X$_0$ is any solution of AX=0, then X'+X$_0$ is a solution of AX=B.

(2) Every solution of AX = B can be written as X = X' + X$_0$where AX' = 0.

It then gives an example,

Let A= $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -2 & 2 & -1\\ 2 & -4 & 3 & 1\\ 3 & -6 & 5 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} $$

and B= $$\begin{pmatrix}1  \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ \end{pmatrix} $$

" Use Gaussian elimination  to express every solution to the system AX=B as the sum of a particular solution and the general solution to the homogenous equation AX=0"

I will skip the steps of reducing but after doing row reductions we come to

$$\begin {pmatrix}  1 & -2 & 0 & 5 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -3 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} $$

Up to here I am still following along, and now I understand we can write

X= $$\begin {pmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \ \end{pmatrix} $$ + s $$\begin {pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \ \end{pmatrix} $$ + t $$ \begin {pmatrix} -5 \\ 0 \\ 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

Where s and t are the two parameters, x2=s and x4=t

The part I really dont understand and am looking for help with is what the book states after this. It then says The particular solution X0 is $$\begin {pmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \ \end{pmatrix} $$ and the general solution to the homogenous equation is

s$$\begin {pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \ \end{pmatrix} $$ + t $$ \begin {pmatrix} -5 \\ 0 \\ 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

My main question is how from this theorem were we able to know that the solution without the parameters was a solution in itself, are the parameters not part of the solution? And especially how did we know that the solutions containing  the s and t only and not the constants were solutions to the homogenous equation.

I hope what I am asking makes some sense, thanks all in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you familiar with solving $Ax = 0$ ?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with the homogenous system

Comment: So you do know how to express solution for below equation using parameters $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -2 & 2 & -1\\ 2 & -4 & 3 & 1\\ 3 & -6 & 5 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} \left(\begin{array}\\ w\\x\\y\\z \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}\\ 0\\0\\0 \end{array}\right) $$ ?

Comment: Yes I believe so, I would put into reduced form and use parameters, using x1,x2,x3 and x4 instead I come to , x1=2s-5t x2=2 x3=3t and x4=t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think you may have misstated the first part of the theorem slightly. It should be: If $X_{0}$ is a solution to $AX= B$, and $X'$ a solution to $AX = 0$, then $X_{0} + X'$ is also a solution to $AX = B$, since $A(X_{0} + X') = AX_{0} + AX' = B + 0.$

Now we can write the general solution you computed as 
\begin{equation}
X = X_{0} + sX_{1} + tX_{2},
\end{equation}
where $X_{0} = \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   3 \\
   0 \\
   -1 \\
   0\\
  \end{array} } \right]$, $X_{1} = \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   2 \\
   1 \\
   0 \\
   0\\
  \end{array} } \right]$, and $X_{2} = \left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   -5 \\
   0 \\
   3 \\
   1\\
  \end{array} } \right]$. This solution satisfies $AX = B$ for all choices of $s$ and $t$. In particular then, if we set $s = t= 0$, then we have $AX_{0} = B$, meaning that $X_{0}$ is a particular solution (note there is not a unique particular solution).

So to answer your question, the parameters are part of the general solution; $X_{0}$ is not the solution without parameters, rather it is the solution at particular values of the parameters ($s= t= 0$).

Next, notice that $A(sX_{1} + tX_{2}) = AX - AX_{0} = 0$. So $sX_{1} + tX_{2}$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation for all values of $s$ and $t$.

I think this example was meant to demonstrate the various aspects of the theorem, but you do not need the theorem to deduce all the above facts.